# check if two dataframes have same set of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which I believe have the same data but the rows are not in the same order. How can I check that they have the same rows but perhaps in a different order?

Comment: To get any different rows, `df1 <- mtcars[sample(1:30),]; df2 <- mtcars[sample(3:32),]; union(setdiff(df1, df2), setdiff(df2, df1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first order the two datasets based on the columns

```
tmp1 <- df1[do.call(order, df1),]
row.names(tmp1) <- NULL
tmp2 <- df2[do.call(order, df2),]
row.names(tmp2) <- NULL
```

Then use `all.equal` to check if they are the same

```
all.equal(tmp1, tmp2, check.attributes = FALSE)
```

NOTE: The OP's question is about `How can I check that they have the same rows but perhaps in a different order?`

NOTE2: No external packages are used

Comment: what is the order in your code based on? Is it based on a particular column? What if there is no good column to order on? Could I use the %in% operator?

Comment: @matt This is based on your description `I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which I believe have the same data`

Answer (score 1):

[`dplyr::all_equal`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/all_equal.html) is really useful for this.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_1 <- mtcars

df_2 <- mtcars %>% arrange(mpg) # Change row order

df_3 <- mtcars %>% select(disp, everything()) # change column order

all_equal(df_1, df_2, ignore_row_order = FALSE)
#> [1] "Same row values, but different order"

all_equal(df_1, df_3, ignore_col_order = FALSE)
#> [1] "Same column names, but different order"

all_equal(df_1, df_2, ignore_row_order = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
```