# identify differences in two dataframes with same columns but where rows are not in same order and dataframes have different dimensions

Tags: r

I am modelling something outside of R. Two models should have yielded the same final output numbers but I get different results because of some value differences between the models which are hard to identify because the datasets are huge.

In the following example dfs, where the rows are not in the same order and df1 and df2 have vectors of different lengths but the same column names and classes, I want to isolate the differences between the dfs.

V1 is a factor, V2 is a character variable and V3 is numerical. As you can see, some of V1 entries exist in df2 but not in df1 and some of V3 values are not the same even when V1 and V2 values (but not necessarily positions) match between dfs (see picture).

Goal: I want to know exactly where the differences are so I can change the models to match each other.

I reviewed this post but it does not deal with different dimensions or identifying where the differences are: [check if two dataframes have same set of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253271/check-if-two-dataframes-have-same-set-of-rows)

Hoping you can help.

```
df1 dim = 8x3
V1 = (A,A,B,B,B,C,C) # factor
V2 = (b,a,a,b,c,a,b) # character
V3 = (1,1.5,2,2.5,3,1.5,2) # numeric

df2 dim = 9x3
V1 = c(A,B,B,B,C,C,C,D) # factor
V2 = c(b,a,b,c,a,b,d,a) # character
V3 = c(1,2,2.5, 3,1.5,200,0.5,6) # numeric
```

[df1 and df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtJX.png)

I imagined looking at each row in df1 and searching for an identical row match by content in each row of df1 and if it is not found, creating a df of the difference. This would have to be done in both directions (for looping).  However, I think a for loop wouldn't work because the row positions in the dfs are different

I tried using the compare package but it didnt tell me where and what exactly the differences were.

```
library(compare)
> # Create two sample data frames
> data1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))
> data2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 9), y = c(4, 9, 6))
> # Compare the data frames
> comparison_result <- comparedf(data1, data2)
Fehler in comparedf(data1, data2) : 
  konnte Funktion "comparedf" nicht finden
> # Compare the data frames
> comparison_result <- compareIgnoreOrder(data1, data2)
> print(comparison_result)
FALSE [FALSE, FALSE]
```

Comment: I would take a look at the [waldo](https://waldo.r-lib.org/) package

Comment: I consider down-voting due to the fact that data (`df1` and `df2`) are presented in a lazy and not reproducible manner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Also, the structutre is different to `data1` and `data2`. Which version mimics your data? Btw is `comparedf()` from `{arsenal}`? I suspect this is why you are running in *Fehler in comparedf(data1, data2) : 
  konnte Funktion "comparedf" nicht finden*

Comment: maybe you want to add ids to your tables then do some semi joins and anti joins with dplyr. But yeah reproducible data and you'll have a good answer fast, we can't do much with this.